# Chi-square value of newly discovered star S4716

Tags: python, statistics, physics, astronomy, goodness-of-fit

I’m writing my thesis in astrophysics right now. I’m trying to fit a Kepler orbit to the newly discovered star S4716. However, when trying to estimate the reduced chisq value I end up getting a value of 206. I use the same limitations and constant as Peißker et al ( https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-4357/ac752f ). On the other hand , the plot looks decent (See attached files named S4716_Peissker).

Could the error be the lack of data points (21)? Or something totally obvious that I’m not seeing?

There are 20 datapoints where 4 of them have an error of 0.5 i.e. the fit and chisq are totally dominate by these poins and looking at the plot and interpreting a bit, I should end up with a chisq < 2 more or less….

My code can be found at github: https://github.com/donfup/S4716
I have included a fit I did for S2 which works perfectly fine - maybe its useable for inspiration?
The output of my code is attached.
Can anyone see what I’m doing wrong in my calculation of the chisq-value? All help is much appreciated.

My code:

```
# Import the required modules
from __future__ import print_function, division
import numpy as np
#from math import pi
from scipy.constants import *
#from cProfile import label
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from scipy.integrate import odeint
import pandas as pd
#from scipy.optimize import minimize
#from scipy.stats import chisquare
from iminuit import Minuit
#import emcee
#import corner
import math
import kepler



premo=1
prem=1
G1=G*(prem**3)/(premo)*(((365.25*24*60*60)**(2))*3.40367597004765*10**(-50))/((5.02739933*10**(-31)))
c1=c*(3.24077929*10**(-17))*(365.25*24*60*60)*prem                          #speed of light in parsec/year


#######################################fit kepler orbit

def n1(a1,Mbh1):
    n1=((a1**3)/(G1*Mbh1))**(-1/2)
    return n1

def M(tp,t,Mbh1,a1):
    M=n1(a1,Mbh1)*(t-tp)
    return M

def E1(tp,t,Mbh1,a1,e1):
    E1=kepler.solve(M(tp,t,Mbh1,a1), e1)
    return E1

def keprad(tp,t,Mbh1,a1,e1):
    keprad=a1*(1-e1*np.cos(E1(tp,t,Mbh1,a1,e1), dtype=np.float64))
    return keprad

def emel(e1):
    emel=((1+e1)/(1-e1))**(1/2)
    return emel


def theta1(tp,t,Mbh1,a1,e1):
    theta1=2*np.arctan(emel(e1)*np.tan(E1(tp,t,Mbh1,a1,e1)/2, dtype=np.float64), dtype=np.float64)
    return theta1


def dr1(tp,t,Mbh1,a1,e1):
    dr=np.sin(E1(tp,t,Mbh1,a1,e1), dtype=np.float64)*n1(a1,Mbh1)*(a1**2)*e1/keprad(tp,t,Mbh1,a1,e1)
    return dr

def dt2(tp,t,Mbh1,a1,e1):
    dt2=(n1(a1,Mbh1)*(a1**2)*((1-e1**2)**(1/2)))/(keprad(tp,t,Mbh1,a1,e1)**2)
    return dt2

dataorbit = pd.read_excel(r'OrbitdataS4716.xlsx')

def timecon(my_list):
    return [ x-2003.44 for x in my_list ]

def parsec(my_list,Ro1):
    return [ np.tan(((x/1000/3600)*0.0174532925)/2)*Ro1*2 for x in my_list ]

#def velsectoyear(my_list):
#    return [ x*365.25*24*60*60 for x in my_list ]

def power(my_list):
    return [ x**2 for x in my_list ]

def velparsectoyear(my_list):
    return [ x*365.25*24*60*60*prem*3.24077929*10**(-14) for x in my_list ]


#orbit data for S4716
RAS2=list(dataorbit['RA(mas)S4716'])
DECS2=list(dataorbit['Decl(mas)S4716'])
RAerrorS2=list(dataorbit['ErrorRA(mas)S4716'])
DECerrorS2=list(dataorbit['ErrorDecl(mas)S4716'])
#VLRS2=list(dataorbit['Radialvelocity(kmpersec)S2'])
#errorVLSR2=list(dataorbit['Error Radial velocity (kmpersec)S2'])
tid2=list(dataorbit['Time'])
tidS2=timecon(tid2)
#VLRS2=velparsectoyear(VLRS2)
#errorVLSRS2=velparsectoyear(errorVLSR2)

RAS2re= [x for x in RAS2 if str(x) != 'nan']
DECS2re= [x for x in DECS2 if str(x) != 'nan']
RAerrorS2re= [x for x in RAerrorS2 if str(x) != 'nan']
DECerrorS2re= [x for x in DECerrorS2 if str(x) != 'nan']


def LSQXkep(Mbh1,Ro1,oomegaS2,OmegaS2,IS2,tp,a1,e1):                  #least square which we want to minimize
    uuS2=[]
    uuS12=[]
    for i in range(len(DECS2)):
        if math.isnan(DECS2[i]):
            continue
        else:
            radkep=keprad(tp,tidS2[i],Mbh1,a1,e1)
            the=theta1(tp,tidS2[i],Mbh1,a1,e1)
            uuS12.append(radkep)
            uuS2.append(the)
    uuS12=np.transpose(uuS12)
    uuS2=np.transpose(uuS2)
    residulDECS2=np.sum(((parsec(DECS2re,Ro1) - uuS12*(np.cos(OmegaS2, dtype=np.float64)*np.cos(oomegaS2+uuS2, dtype=np.float64)-np.sin(OmegaS2, dtype=np.float64)*np.sin(oomegaS2+uuS2, dtype=np.float64)*np.cos(IS2, dtype=np.float64)))** 2)/power(parsec(DECerrorS2re,Ro1)) , dtype=np.float64)
    residulARAS2=np.sum(((parsec(RAS2re,Ro1) - uuS12*(np.sin(OmegaS2, dtype=np.float64)*np.cos(oomegaS2+uuS2, dtype=np.float64)+np.cos(OmegaS2, dtype=np.float64)*np.sin(oomegaS2+uuS2, dtype=np.float64)*np.cos(IS2, dtype=np.float64)))** 2)/power(parsec(RAerrorS2re,Ro1)) , dtype=np.float64)
    resid=residulDECS2+residulARAS2
    return resid
print('len(S4716)=',len(DECS2))

#initial guess
Mbh=4.023*10**6             #black hole mass in solar mass
R1=8000                     #distance to orbit
oomegaS2g=0.0012            #omega=0.073°= 0.001 rad
OmegaS2g=2.65               #Omega=151.54°=2.65
IS2g=2.814                  #i=161.24° = 2.814 rad
tpg=2
a1g=0.00193
e1g=0.756

print('Chi square before',LSQXkep(Mbh,R1,oomegaS2g,OmegaS2g,IS2g,tpg,a1g,e1g)/((len(RAS2re)+len(DECS2re))-8))


print('fit all same time')
ms = Minuit(LSQXkep, Mbh1=Mbh,Ro1=R1,oomegaS2=oomegaS2g,OmegaS2=OmegaS2g,IS2=IS2g,tp=tpg,a1=a1g,e1=e1g)
ms.limits['e1'] = (0.756,0.756) #Constant limits obtained from article Peissker et al.
#ms.limits['e1'] = (0,1)
ms.limits['oomegaS2']= (0.0012,0.0012)
#ms.limits['oomegaS2']= (0,2*pi)
ms.limits['OmegaS2']= (2.65,2.65)
#ms.limits['OmegaS2']= (0,2*pi)
ms.limits['IS2']= (2.814,2.814)
#ms.limits['IS2']= (0,2*pi)
ms.limits['Ro1']= (8000,8100)
#ms.limits['Ro1']= (7500,8500)
ms.limits['Mbh1']= (4*(10**6),4.1*(10**6))
#ms.limits['Mbh1']= (4*(10**6),5*(10**6))
ms.limits['tp']= (0,10)
tttts=ms.simplex().migrad()
print(tttts)



#global parameters
print('Intial Mbh=',Mbh,'  Fitted Mbh=',ms.values[0])
print('Intial R0=',R1,'  Fitted R0=',ms.values[1])


#Orbit parameters S2
print('Intial omega S2=',oomegaS2g,'  Fitted omega S2=',ms.values[2])
print('Intial Omega S2=',OmegaS2g,'  Fitted Omega S2=',ms.values[3])
print('Intial I S2=',IS2g,'  Fitted I S2=',ms.values[4])
print('Intial tp S2=',tpg,'  Fitted tp S2=',ms.values[5])
print('Intial a S2=',a1g,'  Fitted a S2=',ms.values[6])
print('Intial e S2=',e1g,'  Fitted e S2=',ms.values[7])

Mbhreal=ms.values[0]
R0real=ms.values[1]
oomegareal=ms.values[2]
Omegareal=ms.values[3]
IS2real=ms.values[4]
tpreal=ms.values[5]
areal=ms.values[6]
ereal=ms.values[7]

print('Chi square after',LSQXkep(Mbhreal,R0real,oomegareal,Omegareal,IS2real,tpreal,areal,ereal)/(len(RAS2re)+len(DECS2re))-8)
#print('længde:',len(RAS2re)*2), just to check the length
time1=np.linspace(0,10,1000)

radiplot=[]
thetaplot=[]
for i in range(1000):
    dt=i*10/1000
    radiplot.append(keprad(tpreal,dt,Mbhreal,areal,ereal))
    thetaplot.append(theta1(tpreal,dt,Mbhreal,areal,ereal))

radiplot=np.transpose(radiplot)
thetaplot=np.transpose(thetaplot)

plt.plot(radiplot*(np.sin(Omegareal, dtype=np.float64)*np.cos(oomegareal+thetaplot, dtype=np.float64)+np.cos(Omegareal, dtype=np.float64)*np.sin(oomegareal+thetaplot, dtype=np.float64)*np.cos(IS2real, dtype=np.float64)),
         radiplot*(np.cos(Omegareal, dtype=np.float64)*np.cos(oomegareal+thetaplot, dtype=np.float64)-np.sin(Omegareal, dtype=np.float64)*np.sin(oomegareal+thetaplot, dtype=np.float64)*np.cos(IS2real, dtype=np.float64)),color='grey',label='Fitted orbit S4716')
plt.errorbar(parsec(RAS2,R0real),parsec(DECS2,R0real),xerr=parsec(RAerrorS2,R0real),yerr=parsec(DECerrorS2,R0real),marker='.',capsize=2, ls='none',color="fuchsia",ecolor='violet',label='S4716 Data points')

plt.xlabel('Right ascension [pc]')
plt.ylabel('Declination [pc]')
plt.plot(0,0,'ko',markeredgecolor='orange',label='Sgr. A*')         #plots a black point with orange edge to show the SMBH
plt.legend()
plt.grid(alpha=0.5)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

I’m writing my thesis in astrophysics right now. I’m trying to fit a Kepler orbit to the newly discovered star S4716. However, when trying to estimate the reduced chisq value I end up getting a value of 206. I use the same limitations and constant as Peißker et al ( https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/1538-4357/ac752f ). On the other hand , the plot looks decent (See attached files named S4716_Peissker).

Could the error be the lack of data points (21)? Or something totally obvious that I’m not seeing?

There are 20 datapoints where 4 of them have an error of 0.5 i.e. the fit and chisq are totally dominate by these poins and looking at the plot and interpreting a bit, I should end up with a chisq < 2 more or less….

Comment: Sounds like very interesting problem. I think you can help others help you by showing a table of the predicted values compared to the actual data, and also to highlight just the function you're calling to get the chi square. There is a lot of stuff here, and it's very interesting, but the complexity of it is going to make it more difficult for others to comprehend, and therefore less likely that anyone can help.

Comment: Need real data to check